# Checking if a generic IEnumerable is empty

Tags: c#, linq, generics

Let's say I have an object which *may* be of type `IEnumerable<T>`. I want to write a method that returns true if the object is of type `IEnumerable<T>`, is not null, and is not empty.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
public bool IsNullOrEmpty(object obj)
{
    if (obj != null)
    {
        if (obj is IEnumerable<object>)
        {
            return (obj as IEnumerable<object>).Any();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This works if I pass in an object that is of type `List<string>`, but not if I pass in an object that is of type `List<int>`. It fails because because `obj is IEnumerable<object>` returns `false`.

Any idea how I can make this work for all generic `IEnumerable`s?

Comment: Frankly, it is a bad idea to "fix" this; in the general case, you should never assume that an `IEnumerable[<T>]` is repeatable, in which case: asking `.Any()` may mean that you can never ask for the *actual data*

Comment: What if it is a `List<bool>` that contains one element, `false`

Wouldn't this break the function?

Comment: If you're asking whether the enumeration is *empty*, shouldn't you return the *negated* result of `Any()`?

Comment: @DakotahHicock No - `Any` without a lambda argument will not try to evaluate the contents - it will just check for the presence of any member.

Comment: @DStanley, thank you for clarifying. I didn't know as I've never even thought to use `Any` this way.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Arguably, that is true for any call to `Any()` in the first place, in or outside of the method shown here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since the type may be unknown, you can try check for `IEnumerable` interface and use `MoveNext()` on the enumerator.

**EDIT:** I updated the method name. It makes more sense with the logic now since the original question code was checking if there were items in the collection.

```
public bool IsNotNullOrEmpty(object enumerable)
{
    if (enumerable is IEnumerable e)
    {
        using (var enumerator = e.GetEnumerator())
            return enumerator.MoveNext();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You can't call this on an `object`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey True, I didn't realize the type wasn't known ahead of time. I'll try and update.

Comment: Your approach doesn't try to `Dispose` the `IEnumerator` that you created with `GetEnumerator`.

Comment: `enumerable is IEnumerable` actually already performs the null check, so you can remove the line `if (enumerable != null)`

(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx: 
An is expression evaluates to true if the provided expression is non-null, and the provided object can be cast to the provided type without causing an exception to be thrown.)

Answer (score 10):

[`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) inherits from [`System.Collections.IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - thus, if you are ok with checking the non-generic `IEnumerable`, rather than the generic `IEnumerable<T>`, you could just cast to `IEnumerable`.

A few notes about your code: You are first checking with `is`, and then you cast with `as`. That is generally unnecessary; `as` already checks and returns `null` if the cast failed. Therefore, a shorter way would be:

```
var enumerable = obj as IEnumerable;
if (enumerable != null) {
    return !enumerable.Cast<object>().Any();
}
```

Note that you will need the additional call to [`Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) there, as [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) requires a generic `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to cast it to  `IEnumerable`:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this T obj) where T : class
{
    if (obj == null) return true;
    IEnumerable seq = obj as IEnumerable;
    if (seq != null) return !seq.Cast<object>().Any();
    return false;
}
```

...

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
bool nullOrEmpty = list.IsNullOrEmpty();  // true
```

Btw, interestingly enough it works correctly with an empty string:

```
bool nullOrEmpty = "".IsNullOrEmpty();   // true
```

Comment: I didn't know you could attach an extension method to an arbitrary `T` type.  Would this extension method show up for any class?

Comment: Why should this be a generic method? You aren't using type `T` in your method, and as you're not attempting to assign `null` to any identifier of type `T`, you are not using any of the guarantees provided by the generic constraint, either.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: why should it be allowed to use it on a value type like `int`? It needs to be generic to use the class constraint.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: only for reference types. So you can `"".IsNullOrEmpty()` but not `1.IsNullOrEmpty()`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Why should it *not* be allowed to use it on a value type like `int`?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: That's not true, the method as shown compiles just fine without the constraint. As I said, the constraint just enables `null` *assignments* to variables of type `T`; comparisons with `null` are always possible, even without the constraint (they'll just always return `false` for value types).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: because of OP's specification: _"returns true if the object is of type IEnumerable<T>, is not null, and is not empty"_ What is an empty value type?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: What's an empty non-null non-collection reference type?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: the method name is `IsNullOrEmpty` and that is also the requirement. If i want to check if a collection is empty i don't need a new method.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Indeed. Hence, no reason to exclude value types.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: a value type is never null and never empty. I also don't see why you need an extension method on a value like `4711`. You could just compare it with whatever you want. What is empty at all, `int.MinValue`, `0`, `int.MaxValue`,etc?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: A non-collection reference type is never empty. If this `IsNullOrEmpty` method can be applied to things that are never empty, why can't it be applied to things that are never `null`?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: because per definition `IsNullOrEmpty` has two use cases: 1. check if an object is `null`(reference type) and 2. check if an `IEnumerable` is empty. Btw, as mentioned in the answer `string` is an interesting example since the method also replaces `String.IsNullOrEmpty` correctly.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Where is that definition from? Also, have you thought about what happens if you pass an `object` variable to your method that points to a boxed `int` value? That way, you can still pass an `int` value to your method, and the method would (correctly!) return `false`, because the `int` value is neither `null` nor empty. Why wouldn't you allow the same to happen when the `int` value is explicitly typed? Also, think of generic scenarios - if the type `T` is not known (but provided as a generic argument itself), you would force calling code to restrict its own generic argument, too.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: the definition is from OP's requirement and from the name of the method ( value types cannot be null and only sequences can be empty ). Of course you can always trick constraints or other language features like acccess modifiers(f.e reflection) if you want. But a constraint should only _help_ to prevent obvious errors. `int.MinValue.IsNullOrEmpty` is a code smell, it is neither correct nor incorrect, only the calling method knows.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I don't see any part of the OP's requirement that excludes value types. The name of the method cannot be used as proof here - by your logic, you would also have to exclude non-collection types, as only sequences can be empty. I am not sure how `int.MinValue.IsNullOrEmpty` is "neither correct nor incorrect", as any `int` value obviously does not equal `null`, so there can be no doubt about how to answer that part of the question.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: i don't need to exclude other types even if they are not collections since the method can be used to check if an object is `null` if `T` is a reference type. `int` is never null, true, but is it also always non-empty? My point is that it's just confusing to introduce code like `0.IsNullOrEmpty`, it is also pointless since `num == 0` is much more clear. But let us end the discussion, it's subjective.

Answer (score 3):

You can check for the non-generic `IEnumerable` and check that for emptiness. You can add a check to ensure the object implements `IEnumerable<T>` using reflection:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(object obj)
{
    var e = obj as System.Collections.IEnumerable;
    if (e == null || !e.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))) return false;

    foreach (object _ in e)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to `Dispose` the `IEnumerator` after the `MoveNext` call if it's an `IDisposable`? The `foreach` always does.

Comment: @NathanA: `s/IEnumerable/IEnumerator/`?

Comment: @NathanA - I thought so too but the non-generic `IEnumerator` does not implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: If you look at what `foreach` does internally, it uses a `try/finally` clause, which in turn, disposes the object when it falls out of scope, *only if it's an IDisposable*.  The same thing would need to be done here.

Comment: @Lee: How do you know that an arbitrary class that implements the non-generic `IEnumerator` does not also implement `IDisposable`, because it internally uses some unmanaged resources?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - You don't but that is also how `foreach` works. I update it to use `foreach` for consistency.

Comment: @Lee: I am in favour of disposing the enumerator, if possible. My question was in response to your claim that "`IEnumerator` does not implement `IDisposable`".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - I meant `IEnumerator` does not inherit from `IDisposable` directly itself, obviously a class could implement both.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, adding the state-of-the-art answers for the recent c# versions (from c#8.0):

```
static bool IsNotNullOrEmpty<T>(object obj) => obj is IEnumerable<T> seq && seq.Any();
static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(object obj) => !(obj is IEnumerable<T> seq && seq.Any());
```

This assumes you will know `T` in the calling site.

If you won't know `T`, you shouldn't be using `IEnumerable<object>`, but `IEnumerable` instead. Something like this:

```
static bool IsNotNullOrEmpty(object obj) => obj is IEnumerable seq && seq.GetEnumerator().MoveNext();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first check if the object implements `ICollection` like lists and arrays do, as checking the size of one of those is cheaper as they have a `Count` property. If it's not you can check if it implements `IEnumerable` and if it does, create an enumerator and see if you can move to the first item:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(object obj) {
  ICollection c = obj as ICollection;
  if (c != null) {
    return c.Count == 0;
  }
  IEnumerable e = obj as IEnumerable;
  if (e != null) {
    return !e.GetEnumerator().MoveNext();
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: If you're just looking for the `Count` field, why do you insist on `IList` rather the more general, less restrictive [`ICollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Good point. I was thinking of the implementation of the `Enumerable.Count<T>` extension method, and thought that I recalled that it checks for `IList`, but it actually checks for `ICollection` when I recheck the code.

Answer (score 0):

This answers expands the question outside of the `IEnumerable<T>` scope to "can this thing I have be used in a `foreach`-loop?".

As you might known, `foreach` does not check for `IEnumerable` primarily, but rather tries to enumerate whatever is given.

This will work for all types which in some sense is enumerable in the sense that `foreach` thinks:

```
public bool IsNullOrEmpty(object obj)
{
  if (obj != null) // we can't be null
  {
    var method = obj.GetType().GetMethod("GetEnumerator");
    if (method != null) // we have an enumerator method
    {
      var enumerator = method.Invoke(obj, null);
      if (enumerator != null) // we got the enumerator
      {
        var moveMethod = enumerator.GetType().GetMethod("MoveNext")
        if (moveMethod != null) // we have a movenext method, lets try it
          return !(bool)moveMethod.Invoke(enumerator, null); // ie true = empty, false = has elements
      }
    }
  }
  return true; // it's empty, lets return true
}
```

This basically does the same as the `foreach`-loop, ie checks for enumerability and doesn't really give a darn about the types involved.

As such it should really be avoided, but if you somehow have to check if you can put your type in `foreach`-loop this should do the trick.

Comment: Downvoter? Care to comment? You understand this is more generic than checking for `IEnumerable`? `ForEach` does kinda like this.

Comment: well.... I think it's a bad idea to use reflection instead of casting to IEnumerable. You're putting a lot of constraints on unknown code, If you use IEnumerable it is clear to the interface implementer what the GetEnumerator and MoveNext methods SHOULD do. Reflection also comes with some performance penalties.

Comment: @DominikvonWeber I am actually doing the same procedure as the `foreach`-implementation, and I clearly state that I'm checking for enumerability not `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerable<T>`-implementation (a world of difference). Do consult the C# specification if you do not agree on that. This answer is added after accept of cast to `IEnumerable` since I do not believe that covers it, and following the behaviour of `foreach` would be more consistent with the framework.